# Fast Forward and fastBackward with sound in ActionScript3, is it possible?

Tags: audio, actionscript, fast-forward

Is it possible to create functionality like fast forward and fast backward of given sound file that plays in swf with AtionScrip3 and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

Take a look at [SampleDataEvent](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6), it allows you to manipulate the bytes of a sample before it is played. To play faster, to just have to skip one float every two. To play slower, to may write twice the same float.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this, it "stutters" or repeats subsecond samples. Its as if it expects to take up N amounts of time and if your sample is N/2 mills long, it loops.